# How do I customize Bootstrap?

Tags: web-development, css, websites, bootstrap

I am a desktop programmer but currently I am trying to develop a website. I know HTML, CSS, Javascript and PHP but writing the complete code from scratch isn't encouraged and well, I end up with weird website which messes up from screen to screen.

I switched to Bootstrap but it is predefined. I mean, the container and jumbotron and everything else has predefined attributes.

How can I use the same element on one page and another with different attributes (height, width, color). Should I use in-style CSS for things I want to change or should I keep on making different .CSS files for every page.

For example; in the following code, I am using a container to show something but now I want two containers. The second one should be wider and have a different color and font. Should I use in-style CSS or should I just create a new selector giving it a new name "container-2".

```
<div class="jumbotron" style = "background-color:#18bc9c">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <p>Just a test</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-success btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've submitted a request to edit your post, but I would also recommend you consider condensing your question a bit to keep it simple and concise. Try to get to the point and maybe even provide an example.

Comment: @RowanFreeman Hi, I tried keeping it short but I will review it again. And I gave an example with the containers and jumbotron. Is that not enough? Or should I try something else? I mean, you understand what I am trying to ask in the question?

Comment: By examples I mean with code. I think I know what you're asking but the message could be clearer.

Comment: @RowanFreeman Is this example ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You question is a bit of a broad/opinionated *"What's the best way to manage the whole CSS thing?"*.

It's a great question, but I don't think there is a single answer. I feel like the question is ultimately, *"How do you **work with** Bootstrap?"*

Bootstrap is a front-end framework. Frameworks generally include a lot of features but, by their nature, are **a structure to build upon**.

I'll divide my answer into two parts, each for a different scenario. You might be either:

- A small to medium business or hobby website with little customisation required.
- A large business or complex website requiring heavy modification.

### Small-scale

Examples: [AussieOutages](https://aussieoutages.com/archive/), [{less}](http://lesscss.org/)

You might easily get away with a CSS file or two to deal with all of these things. If you mostly use the built-in Bootstrap features, but occasionally need to resize or lightly restructure a component, just make a new CSS file and add in the requirements.

Personally, when I am using Bootstrap for light-modification use, I might use a CSS file called `bootstrap-mod.css` or `bootstrap-custom.css`.

The purpose of this file is to directly modify bootstrap components so that I have them all in a central location.

In another CSS file I might have classes the compliment native Bootstrap components without actually overriding anything. For example I might create a CSS class called `btn-flashy`. The new class doesn't override any CSS styling, but maybe adds a new hover effect to make a button flash.

### Large-scale

This is for websites that take Bootstrap and make heavy modifications to the extent that they may not be recognisable as Bootstrap users on initial viewing.

Here you will be taking the [Bootstrap source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) and using tools like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and CSS extention languages like [{less}](http://lesscss.org/).

---

> *How can I use the same element on one page and another with different attributes (height, width, color). Should I use in-style CSS for things I want to change or should I keep on making different .CSS files for every page.*

Inline styling is frowned upon. Use CSS files. A page can have its own CSS file, but it might be overkill. Instead try to name classes in a meaningful way. For example, if you need to change heights, widths and colours for a component, follow Bootstrap's example by using `my-component-lg`, `my-component-wide` and `my-component-bright` etc.

Comment: That was just exactly what I was looking for. So I am just trying to make a social website(like ask.fm) with simple design for now (I guess), so I will go with small-scale idea. I will keep a couple of CSS file with modifications. I just have to ask for an advice. Is Bootstrap better than regular CSS? I mean I know it is better but since it is slowing me down because it is new for me; what do you suggest? Will it help in the long run? Is it better? Is it useful?